# Typelite error: Running transformation: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types

Tags: visual-studio-2017, typelite

I'm using Typelite 1.8.4 to generate my Typescript classes from c# classes.

When I start Visual Studio 2017 and do a "Run Custom Tool" on TypeLite.Net4.tt it works perfectly and it is generating the Typescript classes. But when I try it again, it fails with this error:

> Running transformation: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
>
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
>
> at TypeLite.TsModelBuilder.Add(Assembly assembly) in 
>   C:\Users\Lukas\Source\Repos\TypeLITEv1\TypeLite\TsModelBuilder.cs:line 134
>   at TypeLite.Net4.TypeScriptFluentExtensions.ForLoadedAssemblies(TypeScriptFluent ts) in C:\Users\Lukas\Source\Repos\TypeLITEv1\TypeLite.Net4\TypeScriptFluentExtensions.cs:line 15
>
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating9A6A0626656F4B1B1A666FE3F7627C9E3D094486020135F96EA52B0B12A8F2A3ADF349B4229C4882A5008416F0CCFFB9B9AB22544159413BEC922E10DC8E87A3.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()  MyAppName   C:\VSTS\MySolutionName\MyProjectName\Scripts\TypeLite.Net4.tt   1

After closing Visual Studio and reopening it again, the 'Run Custom Tools' works fine again and is generating the Typescript classes. But it fails every second try after restarting Visual Studio and the TypeLite.Net4.d.ts becomes empty

How can I get the Typelite generation of classes working again all the time without an error?

Comment: I have the same problem. I don't have to restart VS. Only Closing the solution and opening it again, allow me to build again for one time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is causing this but if you don't want to close VS/Solution you can `clean solution` and after that `rebuild` and it will work again.